# How to classify my favorite questions?

Tags: support, bookmarks

I want to add categories to my favorite questions (for example, I want to add folders customizing, then put questions into different folders). If do it like this, when I want to review my favorite questiones, I can easily find the specific question.

Comment: You could use the bookmarks in your browser of choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search for your favorite questions using `infavorites:me` with additional parameters and questions have tags already, so you can include `intags:mine` to search for your tags.

See the screenshot below:

[image]

For additional information look https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching

**Update**

To search for specific tag that is in your favorites use the query below:

```
infavorites:me [your-tag]
```

Comment: sometimes i indeed need use my own tag to classify my favorite questions .for example ,just like establish a website may using many different tags. but i want to view them in "website" tag

Comment: That is easy, `infavorites:me [website]` will give you your favorite `website` posts.

Comment: fine . Although not the completely perfect for me .